# How to fix Error 1 installing Apache from source on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache

I'm installing Apache on Ubuntu following this install guide
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/install.html but get an error on the last step when I run the command line below;

```
$ PREFIX/bin/apachectl -k start
```

I've noticed that the referred file (above) does not exist on my server on that path.

When I run `ls -l`, I get this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 agenadinik agenadinik 7067 2011-03-22 14:08 apr-1-config
```

Does anyone know why this inconsistency exist?

The `make install` command also had this error:

```
make[2]: *** [install] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/agenadinik/httpd-2.2.17/srclib/apr-util'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/agenadinik/httpd-2.2.17/srclib'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any idea what is happening incorrectly here and how to get it fixed?

I'm using Apache version 2.2.17 with the built folder name as `httpd-2.2.17` in my home directory at `/home/agenadinik/`.

Comment: you also need the sudo command for things like install, starting and restarting servers.

Comment: I think you should better ask this on http://askubuntu.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Comment: This question belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: You have not to compile software from sources if there is a binary package available. Just run `sudo apt-get install apache2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its a permissions issue. Try

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Got this error: libtool: install: error: cannot install `libaprutil-1.la' to a directory not ending in /usr/local/apache2/lib
- does that mean it is definitely a permissions issue?

Comment: I think it looks like a mis-config issue.  I thought I gave it a path I wanted, but it is talking about a default path.  Any thoughts on this? :)

Comment: The command "sudo apt-get install apache2" ran.  Is apache ready to start and be used?  Since I gave it the apache2 name, how and from where do I start it? - thank you

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start

Answer (score 1):

```
# make clean install
# service mysqld stop
```

this will remove the above errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same error message, in my case it was a permission problem so I used the following command:

```
# sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to run `make clean install` in the directory where you've compiled Apache.

Then, re-compile Apache from source with all necessary options as below;

*All with `sudo` privileges, if required.*

```
# ./buildconf
# ./configure --enable-ssl --enable-so --with-included-apr
# make
# make install
```

Options used above are:

- `--enable-ssl` to enable SSL support,
- `--enable-so` to enable dynamically loaded modules, and
- `--with-included-apr` to make use of the Apache Portable Runtime (APR) supporting library in the `srclib` directory of your Apache project.

After a successful operation, you can now effectively start your Apache server.